# Tool to visualize network topology

Tags: networking, graphs

I am searching for a specific tool to visualize a network topology.
I found images at this [serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/305310/2-cisco-asa-4-cisco-switches-best-way-to-connect-all-together). Does anyone know what tool they were using?

I checked most of the recommendations from this [superuser question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438419/does-anyone-know-a-good-network-graph-visualization-software-just-add-data) but haven't found it yet

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a tool to find the topology or to generate such graphs? Or a 2-in-1 tool?

Comment: I may have used the wrong terminology. Such graph is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 6):

This sort of diagram is typical of those created with [GraphWiz](http://graphviz.org/) using the dot language.

Also worth taking a look at [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/demo.html) especially the traceroute demo, e.g. the following generated from only about 6 lines of code:

[image]

The above example is from http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/demo.html and was generated, from within the scapy shell with:

```
>>> res,unans = traceroute(["www.microsoft.com","www.cisco.com","www.yahoo.com","www.wanadoo.fr","www.pacsec.com"],dport=[80,443],maxttl=20,retry=-2)
Received 190 packets, got 190 answers, remaining 10 packets
   193.252.122.103:443 193.252.122.103:80 198.133.219.25:443 198.133.219.25:80  207.46...
1  192.168.8.1         192.168.8.1        192.168.8.1        192.168.8.1        192.16...
2  82.251.4.254        82.251.4.254       82.251.4.254       82.251.4.254       82.251...
3  213.228.4.254       213.228.4.254      213.228.4.254      213.228.4.254      213.22...
[...]
>>> res.graph()                          # piped to ImageMagick's display program. Image below.
>>> res.graph(type="ps",target="| lp")   # piped to postscript printer
>>> res.graph(target="> /tmp/graph.svg") # saved to file
```

but to generate the same from the python prompt would require a couple of additional imports that are imported by default in the scapy shell.

Comment: Can you please point us to those six lines of code ?

Comment: @MiniMe : Added to answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve. I just did some reading and I realized that all that is in the documentation :-) Shame on me :-)